# Newly Added and Updated contacts form CNContact Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontactstore

How to identify if contact is modified or new contacts are added to phone contacts. I used `CNContactStore` frame work to get phone contacts. First time I need to get all contacts. From second time onwards I need to get modified contacts or newly added contacts only. `ABAddressBook` we can use creationDate and updation date. But in `CNContactStore` apple not providing these two fields. Then how can I know if one particular is added or updated. 
How to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hie, have you got any solution?

Comment: Did anyone got any solution ?

Comment: I'm also interested in a solution to this.  I don't believe there is any api yet for that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73085003/1176162