# Is this the correct way to identify which contact was updated from Notification.Name.CNContactStoreDidChange notification?

Tags: swift, contacts-framework

Basically I have a `Conversation` object that has a `contact: CNContact?` property, and what I want to do is update the contact info when updated. What I am doing now is subscribe to `Notification.Name.CNContactStoreDidChange` notification, get the `CNNotificationSaveIdentifiersKey` identifiers array from the `userInfo` and compare if any of the ids is equal to the conversation's contact id.

The problem is that none of the ids match, they even have different format

Conversation contact identifier: `68269F08-6B22-4B69-BEA1-431805F328D1:ABPerson`

Notification Contact Identifier: `6F959AA0-5EEF-4C38-B9C7-BEA57F270927`

**The questions is:** Is this the correct way to identify which contact was updated?

This is the code:

````swift
//somewhere in the conversation object
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.CNContactStoreDidChange, object: nil, queue: .main) { (notification) in            
            guard
                let conversationContact = self.contact,
                let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
                let indentifiers = userInfo["CNNotificationSaveIdentifiersKey"] as? [String],
                let notificationIdentifier = indentifiers.first else {
                return
            }

            print(conversationContact.formattedName ?? "nil name")
            print("conversationContact.identifier \(conversationContact.identifier)")

            print("notificationIdentifier \(notificationIdentifier)")

            if conversationContact.identifier == notificationIdentifier {
                self.contact = nil
            }
        }
    ```
````

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a very similar question.

Comment: @DanielBrower I did not found a solution for this. Sorry.

Comment: You can find out what changed using [enumeratorForChangeHistoryFetchRequest:error:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore/3294190-enumeratorforchangehistoryfetchr?language=objc) but sadly it's only accessible form Objective-C. See detailed explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73085003/1176162 or use this [Swift wrapper](https://github.com/yonat/ContactsChangeNotifier).